# how to insert client-side validation ajax onSuccess function mvc 4

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, unobtrusive-validation

I have a problem with unobtrusive validation after an ajax.ActionLink, the form submits correctly and when ajax replace div target, not creates the client-side validation.

I have this in the view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new { area = "Area" }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "divTarget" }))
    {
        //html stuff....
            <li>
                <label><br/></label>
                <div class="perfil_datos_botones">
                    <input type="submit" value="Crear cita" id="enviar">
                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Volver", "Action", "Controller", new { area = "Area" }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "get", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "divTarget", OnComplete = "ValidarForm('target')" }, new { @class = "links_botones" })
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    }
```

The OnComplete function:

```
function ValidarForm(sel) {
        var selector = "#" + new String(sel);
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(selector);
    }
```

I put this on the view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and this in the Layout:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval_noajax")
```

this bundle renders jquery-validation plugin without ajax.unobtrusive.js because this generates multiple post on the view

I have tried to use the function in OnSuccess and either works, the validator throws an exception that says: "unobtrusive field is undefined".

I need to reload the client-side validation on every partialView that uses ajax.BeginForm or ajax.ActionLink.

**EDIT 1:**

I found that `$.validator` is `undefined` and I changed the ajax.actionLink by an ajax get by jquery and I still get the error

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems using the builtin Ajax.BeginForm and used JQuery directly instead. Found it was much easier in the end, one of the reasons being that there is tons and tons of documentation about JQuery available, and not that much on MS wrappers for it.

So the fom is just a very classical HTML form, with a simple button: (I removed all the entry fields )

```
<form id="AllCatsForm>
  <table>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
  </table>
</form>
```

then (in between script tags at first, then in a separated .js file)

```
$("#AllCatsForm").ajaxForm({
    url: "/home/GetAllItems",
    type: "POST",
    beforeSubmit: validateCatSelected,
    success: function (data) {
        $("#ListOfBooksHere").html(data);
    }
});
```

the function to check a mandatory entry field was not empty:

```
function validateCatSelected(formData, jqForm, options) {
    var selectedBooksCategory = $("input[name=CategoryNodeId]").fieldValue();
    if (selectedBooksCategory[0] === "0") {
        alert("Please select a Genre or Category before doing a Custom Search.");
        return false;
    }
    itemLoad = 1;
}
```

"ListofBookshere" is just an empty DIV tag used as container for the results of the search:

```
<div id="ListOfBooksHere" style="padding: 5px; min-height: 500px;" />
```

here is (with almost all fields removed) the function in the controller) Note it does return a partial view, but this view is NOT in main view. Its only use is to properly format the data returned into decent html.

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetAllItems(GenericSearchViewModel filter)
        {
            vm = filter;            
            search.Condition = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.Condition) != true) ? vm.Condition : "All";         
            vm.CatsResults.CatsListResults = await GetCatsResults(search);                   
            return PartialView("GetAllItems", vm);        
        }
```

Hope this helps. Using directly JQuery from MVC is not that difficult, and give you a greater control. I am certainly not saying builtins helper are not working or useful, I tried the JQuery direct route as I was starting to get frustrated, and it has been working well for me.

Hope this help,
Bernard

PS- I was going to forget! This code is using the JQuery plugin JQuery Form: http://malsup.com/jquery/form/